# MYSQL - Update ALL empty fields in a single column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Using PhpMyQdmin, how do I update ALL empty fields in a single column. I have tried a few commands I found online but none seem to do it.

Table is called "news" and column is called "profile_4" and type is "varchar(255)"

I tried this:

```
UPDATE news SET profile_4 = 'General' WHERE profile_4 = NULL
```

but it didn't work.

What I need is to update the empty column fields with 'General'

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What have you try so far? What you mean by 'empty'? NULL?  What is data type of column? Please share SHOW CREATE TABLE tbalename output

Comment: see my answer to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE news SET profile_4 = 'General' WHERE profile_4 IS NULL OR profile_4 = ''
```

For full reference see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to
>   test for NULL.

Comment: Hi @rkosegi I have 0 rows effected. What I need is to update the empty column fields with 'General'. I may not have explained very well, sorry.

Comment: @cybercampbell : Are you sure that column are NULL? see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```